# AWS : Replicate Amazon Elastic search and RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, backup, elasticsearch

We are working on an AWS system where we are using Amazon RDS for database purposes and ElasticSearch for indexing. We have a requirement that we require weekly backup of both the services along with an EBS drive.

This way we are able to maintain difference between live and test system.

For EBS, we are using snapshots for replication and with that we are able to differentiate.

How can I create a replica for Elastic search instances and MySQL RDS database which I can use for test instances. I have setup RDS backups manually. I find no option for backing up ElasticSearch cluster which I can use for test instance.

How can I achieve this? Any ideas. Thank you.